# Qt - QPushButton newline not working

Tags: qt, mobile, qt4

I tried \n and \r\n, but I can't get two lines of text to display correctly.  I'm coding a mobile Qt app.

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(QString("long lines of \n text"));
button->setMaximumWidth(320);
```

Comment: I can't see your button from here. What is not correct about the display?  :)

Comment: You mean the line break does not work?

Comment: Sorry, correct - I mean the line break does not work.   The button text overflows the button, thereby making it not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you assign the parent for the button later but when I try that code from within in a QWidget based form and pass a parent in, I get a button with two lines of text on it.

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(QString("long lines of \n text", this));
button->setMaximumWidth(320);
```

Setting the maximum width won't prevent the button from being sized smaller by a layout. The \n should be causing the text to span two lines so something related to a layout is probably restricting the size of the button.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the QString coming from an XML parse.

Comment: That's likely. Reading the characters '\' and 'n' into a QString is not the same as specifying '\n' in a string literal.

Comment: @Frank LoVecchio If xml is used then you must use like that:  aParseString.replace("\\n", "\n");